# Anyone know of a single-pane Markdown editor for MacOS

Tags: software-recommendation, macos, text-editor, markdown

Just looking for an markdown editor that is one pane, and will let me toggle back-and-forth between "edit mode" and "display mode" with a keyboard shortcut.

I really how the cells in python's Jupyter notebooks can be toggled back and forth between markdown content, and want to duplicate that behavior.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [MacDown](https://macdown.uranusjr.com), it is free and although it has possibility to show edit both panes, you can close one pane using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and then you can switch between edit and display mode using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an app that might work out for you, called Versatil Markdown (https://versatilapp.com).  It has a display mode and an edit mode, toggled with <kbd>cmd-return</kbd>.  Might be worth checking out if you're still looking.